# CSS - How to hide extra images

Tags: html, css

I am having a div which holds 3 big images of 720x360px they all are visible to the users but what i want is to show only 1 image at a time.

My html code:

```
<div class="main-slider">

        <div class="slider-large-image">
            <img src="images/floor_guide.png" alt="" width="727px" height="360px" />
            <img src="images/ice_planet.jpg" alt="" width="727px" height="360px" />
            <img src="images/buddy_work.jpg" alt="" width="727px" height="360px" />
        </div>

        <div class="slider-sidebar">
            <img class="image1" src="images/floor_guide.png" alt="" width="240px" height="180px" />
            <img class="image2"  src="images/ice_planet.jpg" alt="" width="240px" height="180px" />
            <img class="image3"  src="images/buddy_work.jpg" alt="" width="240px" height="180px" />
        </div>

    </div>
```

My CSS code:

```
.main-slider{
    height:360px;
    width:1281px;
}

.slider-large-image{
    width:720px;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.slider-large-image img{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

You can see the output here : http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/dPAnr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `display :none;` to those image you dont want to show

you can do this by

```
.dis_none{
   display :none;
}
```

and add class    `dis_none` to image you dont want to show

Comment: You could use a single img tag and use Javascript to change the src.

Comment: @Barmar yup.. absolutely agreed..this would be best idea .... but i there is neither jquery or JavaScript tag so had to say to use display property

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what I think you want is both the div with class `slider-large-image` and `slider-sidebar` to only show one image.

By the way, you have no CSS styling for `slider-sidebar`.

So assuming that is what you want, you basically need to set the width of those divs so that they only show one image, and set `overflow` to `hidden` or `scroll`

for example:

```
css

    .main-slider{
    height:360px;
    width:1281px;
}

.slider-large-image{
    width:360px;  /* CHANGED TO SMALLER WIDTH, to match the width of one image */
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: scroll; /* set overflow to scroll */
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.slider-large-image img{
     display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: no! its not what you understood, the side bar should show the 3 images but the large-image should show only 1, its a design for the slider :)

Comment: Okay, so then I will simply adjust it so that the sidebar stays the same as in your original styling, and only the 'large-image' will have a reduced width and display to scroll (sorry, I meant to say scroll when I said overflow earlier)

Comment: wow what I said earlier was just totally wrong, I meant to use "overflow" instead of "display". My bad. It should be what you want now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use visibility property for the image you want to hide.
Like this: 
         visibility:hidden;